# How to create multiple index on two fields in google Objectify which should not be included in update and create request?

Tags: google-app-engine, entity, objectify, google-search-api

I want to create multiple index in an entity
on ID and creation date
There is one condition i dont want to use these index on update and create of that object
I am using Google objectify
I will use these multiple index in my search query 
Please help?

Comment: what do you mean by "not use on update/create"? do you mean that this index shouldn't be updated/created?

Answer (score 0):

Objectify has a feature called [partial indexes](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Partial_Indexes) , which define conditions  that a certain property has to meet in order to get indexed.

You could hack that so that those indexed fields are only indexed if a given attribute (ej lastOperation) is not create or update.

**Bear in mind tampering with index updates might lead to invalid query results as the index records (used for search) wont match the actual entity values.**

Comment: Thanks alot about partial indexes i will read them and try to use them